# Using MVC Controller as Web API for Client Mobile App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api

I already created a web-based application using ASP.Net MVC. Now I'm planning to build a mobile application for my web-based system using Ionic or React. My question is, could I use my written controller as an API for my mobile app?

Comment: Have you tried? In theory you can, but that depends a lot on how you implemented it. If your actions deal in HTML, it would be hard to reuse on mobile

Comment: Please show us your work.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Actually, I'm still in progress completing my website. I've already completed a few modules. I would like to be prepared in case I could make some changes to my controller class for future application. All my actions return json string for now.

Comment: Than you should be fine. Just because there is Web API does not mean it has to be used. It is conceivable to reuse same controllers for both web and mobile, although devil might be in details and specifics. Anyway, as your question currently stands it is highly subjective

Comment: No! You need to create WEB.API 2.0 app to get benefits of GET POST PUT DELETE. also might be you can reuse your data access layer if you written separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's preferred to write your business in a separate project which called "yourproject.Domain" or "yourproject.BAL" and then you will have the web project and api project wrapping the business to be able to separate authentication and security for both Web and APIs controllers kindly find the below image for more clarification

[asp.net solution structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW3hp.png)

Comment: Wow, this is all new to me. Could you share a link to articles or something that have more clarification on this application layers?

Comment: you welcome could you please mark the answer up if it helps you?